# Why is jhipster-ionic failing?

Tags: ionic-framework, jhipster

When I run generator yo jhipster-ionic then it fails because of errors in node modulus . Can you help ?

```
➜  jhipster-ionic-photo yo jhipster-ionic                     

Welcome to the Ionic Module for JHipster! v5.2.1

? What do you want to name your Ionic application? mobile
? Enter the directory where your JHipster app is located: app

Creating Ionic app with command: ionic start mobile oktadeveloper/jhipster --type angular no-interactive
TypeError: Cannot set property pathExists of #<Object> which has only a getterThe add    command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
  Error: npx ng add @oktadev/schematics@2.1.1 --configUri=auth-info --issuer=null --clientId=null
at module.exports.error (/Users/xxx/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1590:15)
at module.exports.install (/Users/xxx/node_modules/generator-jhipster-ionic/generators/app/index.js:211:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:976:25)
at /Users/xxx/node_modules/run-async/index.js:49:25
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at /Users/xxx/node_modules/run-async/index.js:26:19
at runLoop.add.once.once (/Users/xxx/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:977:11)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
➜  jhipster-ionic-photo
```

Comment: I'll look into this today and try to fix it.

Comment: I just released [v5.2.2](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/generator-jhipster-ionic/releases/tag/v5.2.2). Can you please try updating?

Comment: unfortunately no luck with new version. Same error: Creating Ionic app with command: ionic start mobile oktadeveloper/jhipster --type angular --no-interactive
TypeError: Cannot set property pathExists of #<Object> which has only a getterThe add command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
Error: npx ng add @oktadev/schematics@2.2.0 --configUri=auth-info --issuer=null --clientId=null
    at module.exports.error (/Users/xxx/Projects/jhipster-ionic-photo/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1590:15)
    at module.exp

Comment: I think the error was related to the version of yo. After a uninstall/install it worked with release v5.2.2.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for figuring out the solution. You should add it as the answer so folks know. I'll vote for it! :)

Answer (score 0):

This error was related to the version of yo
I fixed this error by uninstall/install yo and then jhipster-ionic worked